# Config.php security and Facebook Secret Key

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, security

Some how a another developer is getting our app secret and using it to perform HTTPS/API [Banned](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#banned) requests banning our users from our app.

1. How is he getting the Secret Key we only have it listed in our config.php file located on the server. We cannot find any breaches on the server and the config.php is non-readable or shown anywhere.
2. Will the whitelists settings made available by Facebook block the hacker/developer from banning or is it for only blocking changes to the app settings?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to reset the App Secret you are using presently so you could generate a new one and restrict the extent of damage.

You may utilize the `Server IP Whitelist` which according to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/) suggests that

> We also enable you to restrict your API calls to come from a set of white-listed servers. You can set this whitelist by going to the advanced section of your Developer settings in the App Dashboard and set the 'Server whitelist' field.

and you may further utilize `Update Settings IP Whitelist` to restrict changes to your App's settings. Quoting from [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/),

> We allow you to specify a whitelist of IP addresses that must be used to update the app settings. This helps prevent from attacks by ensuring that only developers using the company IP addresses can update the settings.